# generate slope for multiple columns for different timepoints in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, coefficients

my dataset looks like:

```
Sub session timepoint col1  col2   ... coln
001   1      1/2/2000 122    73   
001   2      2/7/2008 131    65
002   1      3/5/2002 80     55
002   2      5/8/2020 67     45
003   1      6/7/2011 99     67
003   2      8/8/2019 111    77
```

I want to apply lm(y~x) and get the data frame of coefficient lm(y~x)$coefficient[[2]], e.g. for Sub 001, slope for col1:lm((131-122)~(date(2/7/2008)-date(1/2/2000))

output like

```
Sub  col1_lmcoefficient  col2_lmcoefficient   ... coln_coefficient
001   0.0030   -0.0027   ...
002   -0.0019   -0.0015   ...
003   0.0040    0.0034  ...
```

I can't transform the data into time difference and column difference and apply lm because it won't generate data for each row and column. Any suggestions on how to proceed this analysis

Comment: Please provide the data code to reproduce it. What's `x` and `y` in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using tidyverse and broom, based on the tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html).

First, I reshape the data to be longer, to more easily apply the same approach to each column of data. Then I nest the time and value data, map to `lm`, and use `broom::tidy` to extract the coefficients. The rest is filtering / reshaping the output.

```
library(tidyverse); library(broom)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Sub:timepoint)) %>%
  nest(data = -c(Sub, name)) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(value ~ timepoint, data = .x)),
         tidied = map(fit, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied) %>%
  filter(term == "timepoint") %>%
  select(Sub, name, estimate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = estimate)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    Sub     col1     col2
  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  0.00304 -0.00270
2     2 -0.00196 -0.00151
3     3  0.00402  0.00335
```

sample data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sub = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), session = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), timepoint = structure(c(10958, 13916, 11751, 
18390, 15132, 18116), class = "Date"), col1 = c(122L, 131L, 80L, 
67L, 99L, 111L), col2 = c(73L, 65L, 55L, 45L, 67L, 77L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: the tutorial is very helpful, thank you again!